# Why does a function decrease in the direction of another vector?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

> The Problem

Let  and $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ be two vectors and $u$ be a function such that
$$u_{a}-u_{b}=-\int\limits_b^a\vec{v}\cdot{d\vec{w}}$$
I need a pure mathematical proof of  "$u$ decreases along the vector $\vec{v}$."

> Information/s that can help

Maybe this could be done with its differential form i.e. $du=-\vec{v}\cdot{d\vec{w}}$ as it becomes simpler. But I can't go any further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: I'm not positive, but you may be able to use the fundamental theorem of calculus. $f(x)=\int_a^xf'(x)dx$. Is there additional context? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @c_gnar I didn't go so far, maybe this could be done by its differential form, I am not sure.

Comment: Is there any other context to the problem? This looks like it could be an instance of the gradient theorem.